# How to program STM32

Tags: stm32

Im a total beginner with programming ARM microcontroller, But I do have experience with AVR and PIC microcontrollers.

Few days back i have purchased (STM32 STM32F103VET6 development) from ebay.com.
I'm now trying to programming this board but I dont know where to start. I have also received a cd which contains some datasheets and some documents (all in chinese).

could someone tell me how to start? or have some source samples...

I have already installed Keil uVision4. I also have a J-link debugger.

thank you.

Comment: duplicate here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/how-to-program-stm32-development-board

Comment: I would recommend to start with using mbed. It is easier that way and if you have done PICs is a breeze.Plus you don't need to install an IDE. Later you can go to programming HAL and using your uVision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have almost everythin to start. 
Now you may need the STM firmware library. You can download it from the www.st.com web site (http://www.st.com/internet/com/SOFTWARE_RESOURCES/SW_COMPONENT/FIRMWARE/stm32f10x_stdperiph_lib.zip). It contains also a lot of examples.
Which board did you get?
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I may have the same board actually. At first that cd will appear useless but once you explore it a bit you will find that there are a bunch of examples written for that board. I suggest that you start with the most basic example (usually GPIO). Often the more complex examples (MP3 Player and others) have a lot of errors that have to be worked out and it a huge headache for beginners.

your next step would be to find the data sheet for that specific chip. Then loop at the dev board diagrams and find a pin with an LED connected, try to get it to flash. Once you've done that the sky is the limit.

Happy programming